# Print command-line progress bar horizontally

Tags: python-2.7, console-output

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

count  = 5
temp = True
while temp:
        if count < 1:
                print "done",
                temp = False
        else:
                print "*"
                time.sleep(2)
                count -= 1
```

output:

```
*
*
*
*
*
done
```

Please note that here "*" in  output is printed one after the other on the screen at the interval of 2 seconds(this is exactly what i wanted),i need to use this as a progress bar in some other code.

1. I used `print "*",`
   however the output is horizontal but it prints all at once after the program execution.

   ```
   >>>* * * * * done
   ```
2. using `end` keyword gives this error.

   ```
   File "progress_1_.py", line 11
    print ("*",end = '')
                       ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   ```

Python version is Python 2.7.5 .

I cannot upgrade Python on this prod machine and need to deal with the existing version to get the desired output.

So, considering the above cases, instead of printing in new line ,can it be printed horizontally one after the other at the interval of 2 secs?

Comment: You should install 2.x locally so you can write and test code that will actually work in prod, but note that you can `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: @chetan, I tried your code as below, and it works as expected. The code I used is:   import time

count = 5 
temp = True 
while temp:
 if count < 1:
  print "done", 
  temp = False
 else:
  print "*",
  time.sleep(2)
  count -= 1

Comment: However, I added a comma in the print "*"

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you most by clicking the grey check symbol on its left. This marks your question as solved and also rewards the answerer a few points. Thanks!

Comment: Please run the code as a Python script, with the comma after the print "*", this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one simple answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import time

def wait(n):
    time_counter = 0
    while True:
        time_counter += 1
        if time_counter <= n:
            time.sleep(1)
            sys.stdout.write("*")
            sys.stdout.flush()
        else:
            break
    sys.stdout.write("\n")
wait(10)

Output:

**********
```

You can modify the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

The `print` statement of Python 2 is not as flexible as the function from Python 3.

If you used Python 3, you could simply specify the end character and whether to immediately flush the buffer like this:

```
print("*", end="", flush=True)
```

However, as you're using Python 2, you can not use the `print` statement but have to access the output stream object directly:

```
import sys
def progress_print(character="*"):
     sys.stdout.write(character)
     sys.stdout.flush()
```

This will force Python to not cache the printing data until one line is completed, but display it immediately by flushing the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You can skip buffering for a whole python process by using `python -u`

Or when you need to use python 2, you could also replace `sys.stdout` with some other stream like wrapper which does a flush after every call.

```py
class Unbuffered(object):
   def __init__(self, stream):
       self.stream = stream
   def write(self, data):
       self.stream.write(data)
       self.stream.flush()
   def __getattr__(self, attr):
       return getattr(self.stream, attr)

import time
import sys
sys.stdout = Unbuffered(sys.stdout)
print '*',
time.sleep(2)
print '*'
```